# Is POW required for a private blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, proof-of-work

PoW is a mechanism to keep block chain incorruptable from malicious nodes.
Now in a private block chain where all nodes are supposed to be honest, what purpose PoW would serve? Would it not be just a waste of computational power?

Comment: What do you try to achieve from having a blockchain?

Comment: Why using blockchain if all the nodes are supposed to be honest ?

Comment: @AdrienForbu to agree on the state, if 5 companies are honest but they want to share a db, blockchain might be a good solution. of course without PoW. I know it's not where the blockchain shines but still a valid use-case imo. Honest != never make mistakes, blockchain makes sure there is global ordering of transactions and there is only 1 state they all agree.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at this [article](https://medium.com/blockchain-review/private-blockchain-or-database-whats-the-difference-523e7d42edc).

To resume some of the points :

- A private blockchain is a form of shared database
- Different consensus protocols than Proof Of Work exist for private/permission blockchains
- Check out [Quorum](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum) and [Hyperledger Fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) for enterprise blockchain solutions under active development

Answer (score 1):

Proof of work is not required on a permissioned or private blockchain.

For the more efficient operation, for example Proof-of-Authority can be used, like in Ethereum Kovan testnet.

Answer (score 1):

In general, PoW is immoral in it's waste of energy. Other consensus algorithms are available that do are more energy efficient, such as

- PoS (Proof of Stake) used by Ethereum (winner has the most "stake" or "wealth" of some kind)
- PBFT (Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance) elects a leader. Does not scale due to the high number of messages between nodes.
- Raft (which elects a leader until the leader times-out). Scales well and is efficient. Not BFT (vulnerable to bad actor nodes)
- PoET (Proof of Elapsed Time) (which generates a random wait time and the first timer to expire wins)

Comment: PoS is not used by Ethereum at the moment, they have plans to upgrade in the near future though